# How do I upload a simple swf for flash game site?

Tags: php, upload, flash

Swf and I want to upload a picture file. Codes are as follows. What is the problem?

```
if ($_FILES["o_img"]["error"] > 0 and $_FILES["o_swf"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["o_img"]["error"] . "<br />";
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["o_swf"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    if (file_exists("../resimler" . $_FILES["o_img"]["name"]) and file_exists("../swf" . $_FILES["o_swf"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["o_img"]["name"] . "bu isimde bir resim daha önce yüklenmiş ";
      echo $_FILES["o_swf"]["name"] . "bu isimde bir resim daha önce yüklenmiş ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["o_img"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["o_img"]["name"]);
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["o_swf"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["o_swf"]["name"]);

      }
    }
```

My Form:

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
      <p>
         <input type="text" name="o_baslik" id="o_baslik" />
:        Oyun İsmi</p>
      <p><br />
  <input type="text" name="o_etiketler" id="o_etiketler" />
        :
        Oyunun Etiketleri</p>
      <p><br />
        <input type="file" name="o_img" id="o_img" />
        :Oyun Resmi        </p>
      <p><br />
        <input type="file" name="o_swf" id="o_swf" />
        SWF Dosyası<br />
      </p>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

My errors=

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/71IwNCX6PhL__SL1500_.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php on line 65

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpD014.tmp' to 'upload/71IwNCX6PhL__SL1500_.jpg' in C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php on line 65

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php:6) in C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php on line 77
```

Comment: There are **NOT** such word as "codes"!

Comment: Check if the script has write access to that folder. Also, your script has security flaws. What if I upload a PHP file?

Comment: @daGrevis There is such a word as "codes" (but it is indeed misused in this post), and the sentence "There are NOT such word as 'codes'" itself has at least two grammatical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's the problem?

First of all, if only one of files will have error, then your script will proceed and end up with failure. So you should change `and` to `or` in first line.

Furthermore, `$_FILES["filename"]["name"]` has no slash in front of it, so your `file_exists("../resimler" . $_FILES["o_img"]["name"])` will always return `false`.

Then you should check that destination directory is writable for your script - use `is_writable()` function.

Then check you web server configuration to know what is the largest file allowed to be uploaded. For PHP look in php.ini for something similar to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 16M
post_max_size = 18M
```

Comment: errors = 

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/71IwNCX6PhL__SL1500_.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php on line 65

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpD014.tmp' to 'upload/71IwNCX6PhL__SL1500_.jpg' in C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php on line 65

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php:6) in C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\admpanel\yeni.php on line 77

Comment: You have a clear error: directory you are trying to move your uploaded file cannot be found. That happens because there are no `upload` directory in the directory with your script. It's always better to provide an absolute path to dir. In you case it should be something like: `move_uploaded_file("C:\AppServ\www\tasarim\upload\" . $filename)`

Comment: And @Yusuf make sure this directory really exists.